# (trivial proof) show that $(x-1)(x-3)\geq -2$

Tags: proof-writing

I'm taking my first math course that requires me to write proofs, and even though I understand most of the course material, I'm struggling with actually proving things in a rigorous way.

For example, we're asked to show (using what they've called the trivial method of proof) that $$\text{if } x^3-5x-1\geq 0\text{,} \; \text{then}\;  (x-1)(x-3)\geq -2\text{.}$$
I get that the trivial method means were dont really need to use the "if" case to show that the "then" case is true, and I can see that it *is* true, but how do I formally show it?

Comment: That's a really weird thing to call a method of proof, and I think it's a bad idea. Regardless: Forget about the "if" part and notice that $(x - 1)(x - 3)$ is a quadratic that's minimized at $x = 2$.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, this may sound really dumb, but how can you see that its minimised at 2?

Comment: Draw the graph and notice that $x = 2$ is half way between the roots. Or do a line of calculus. (Or expand and complete the square).

Answer (score 2):

HINT: You can rewrite $(x-1)(x-3)\geq -2$ as $(x -2)^2 + 1 \geq 0$

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer, I understand the math but Im just after some help with the formal aspect of writing the proof.

Comment: I think something is wrong with the sentence: if .. then, because what you have after then is true for all x, regardless the condition from "if".

Comment: yep, thats why its asking for a 'trivial' proof, my question was how to formally show that (x−1)(x−3)≥−2 is always true. As in, not so much the math side of it, but the proof writing side.

Comment: I just have giving you a hint!

Comment: yes, thanks for that, but im not really looking for a hint so much as advice on how to formally structure and write the proof. how to state on paper, the problem, and get to QED, in words.

Comment: The difficulty here is that the problem isn't one which needs rigorous formal language to prove it. This is compounded by the fact that we don't know the standards/levels of formality/rigor expected for your class.

Comment: hey ian, yeah its annoying, the class is putting a LOT of stress on showing things with watertight logical proof, so, while i understand the hint, im just not sure if i can use it as the graphs of the two functions (x−1)(x−3) and (x−2)^2+1 are different? i agree that the simplicity of the question add a degree of difficulty to it that is ironic, but yeah, i really have no idea how to even start 'proving' this.

Answer (score 0):

You can structure your proof as follows:
$$(x-1)(x-3)\ge-2$$
$$x^2-4x+5\ge0$$
$$(x-2)^2+1\ge0$$
$$\text{True, as }u^2\ge0 \forall u\in\mathbb R\text{, which follows that }u^2+1\ge0.$$